# Excel: How to link, track and auto update rows in different worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, links

I'm creating a sales pipeline in an excel workbook and there is a tool I would like to use but I can't seem to crack it.

I have multiple worksheets, the first one is a summary to be viewed by sales director and the other ones are sheets for each individual sales person. Each salesperson has a specific worksheet where he adds info on the client, deal size, past action next action and so on. Each client has its own row, and leads are ordered by quarter.

The complicating aspect is that the summary sheet is password protected and not accessible to the salesperson.

I would like to have a macro that links and tracks the info in each row and links it to the summary sheet so that any info added in any of the individual sales worksheet is automatically updated in the summary worksheet.

I have tried linking the cells between each other but it becomes problematic when the salesperson needs to insert a row into his worksheet (precisely because the salesperson cant access the summary sheet).
To circumvent this I wanted to create a macro that when used inserted a new row in the salesperson's sheet, inserted a new row in the summary sheet and linked the cells between both sheets, but excel wont let me link cells in a macro.

Do any of you have a workaround for this problem?

Many thanks for taking the time to read!!

Comment: How is the summary worksheet aggregated? Is it a pivot table or something much less desirable?

Comment: Just a normal table. I have thought about a pivot table, do you think that would make it easier ?

Comment: Definitely. Just keep the input ranges the entire columns and you'll just need to refresh the pivot table once to bring in all new info.

Comment: You could use dynamic named ranges and/or data tables to ensure that new rows are included in the summary data. Exactly how you'd set it up would depend on the layout of your data.  You could also use dynamic named ranges or data tables as the data source for the pivottable @JaredT suggested.

Comment: I apologize for the bad wording, the summary sheet does not summarise the data into sum/average/count or anything, it should merely aggregates the data situated in the individual worksheets into one worksheet and hopefully autoupdate as data is added/modified/removed in the individual worksheets. Is this a feature Excel offers ?

Answer (score 0):

I too would use a pivot table with dynamic ranges/tables as the data source. You may have to refresh to get the most recent updates. One concern I have with this approach is the potential for data loss if one or more of the source spreadsheets are not available.  Excel's documentation should help with that.

Your end result is a common need in business. So another option is to look into free sales pipeline tools.  One I found was an [Excel spreadsheet from Hubspot](https://www.hubspot.com/sales/templates/free-sales-pipeline), that would keep you using a familiar app. You could investigate options on a wiki like [Sales and Marketing Stack](http://salesmarketingstack.com/display/wiki/Sales+Pipeline+Tools).